# Visual Studio Debugger - Visualising Intel Quadruple precision (_Quad)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, intel

I'm using Intel C++ Compiler from within Visual Studio 2008. I was experimenting with the Intel quadruple precision type (`_Quad`). Everything seems to be working fine, except for the debugging. Visual Studio visualiser is unable to peek into `_Quad` values.

What's worse, the visualiser is unable to provide the type information about the `_Quad` value, giving enigmatic three question marks: `???` (as on the attached screenshot)

[image: Debugger Visualiser]

The value is `0` while it should be something else.

Would appreciate some hints on how to attack this puzzle. To work with `autoexp.dat` I need the VS to pickup the type, don't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_Quad is a keyword for Intel C++ compiler, which means it's type info is proprietary and not understandable by Microsoft tools.  To display it in VisualStudio Debugger/IDE, you'll need VisualStudio extensions that can interpret this type for the debugger/IDE.  You might want just contact Intel and see if they have any extensions for you to use in VisualStudio.